# Is there any performance advantage brought about through using Unity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been coding like this in my application:

```
public class ContentController : ApiController
{
    private IUow _uow;
    private IContentService _contentService;

    public ContentController(
        IUow uow,
        IContentService contentService)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _contentService = contentService;
    }
```

and then:

```
    container.RegisterType<IContentService, ContentService>();
```

I started out this way because I kept reading how I should use interfaces for everything to make things testable and use things like Unity to make it easy to change things.

But after one year or more I still don't find the need to change anything and I can test my application in other ways without having a need for different services.

For a small application (< 20 controllers) is there really any advantage to using things like Unity. How about for performance. Does it improve anything or just complicate matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a small application (< 20 controllers) is there really any
>   advantage to using things like Unity.

Yes, because it makes you write more weakly coupled code.

> How about for performance. Does it improve anything or just complicate matters.

No, it doesn't improve performance.

> and I can test my application in other ways without having a need for different services.

If you do not use interfaces to weaken the coupling between the different layers of your application don't be fooling yourself into thinking that you are unit testing your application. What you are doing is integration testing which is also necessary but it serves a different purpose.

It's not important whether you are using a DI framework such as Unity. You could pretty easily row your own DI in just a couple lines of code. What's important is to program against interfaces.